# Keep /run/user/$UID until reboot

Tags: centos, systemd, tmpfs

Is it possible to maintain the /run/user/$UID directory for all users until a machine reboots? To be clear, if a user logs off and all their processes end/are closed, I still like that user's corresponding /run/user/$UID to exist for the next time they login (and removed if the machine restarts).

I am running Centos 8.1.1911 (4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [loginctl(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/loginctl.1.html).

```
loginctl enable-linger USERNAME
```

Comment: Does this need to be done upon each reboot?

Comment: @saladi No, it's permanent. State is saved under `/var/lib/systemd/linger`.